# does angularJS use a different set of rules for ARIA?

Tags: html, angularjs, label, wai-aria, wcag2.0

im working on updating a site for compliance. the site is mostly AngularJS which im still new to but learning. i found a situation where there is a label targeting a div tag however the label has no :for attribute, instead has an :id and the div has a :label-id targeting the :id of the label tag...when i tried to adjust it, it broke on the front-end so im not sure what im seeing...im curious if this will pass WCAG AA?

i have tried a screen reader, NVDA, no issues...however a crawler i used flagged the label element for not having a :for attribute...i have tried searching for the :label-id attribute with no luck which im guessing means its custom...im guessing a lot of the issue is related to my lack of understanding angularJS...

```
<div class="groupA">  
  <label id="elementA">Element A is for Apple</label>
  <div class"customSelectA" label-id="elementA">...stuff shows up here after clicking the label and there are also a bunch of angular attributes on this div that are not relevant to my question</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend going to the basics and ignoring angular for the moment.

Look at the spec for the [`<label>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-label-element) element.  It has a `for` attribute that can point to a form element.  The ID must point to a "[labelable element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#labelable-element)" (<input>, <button>, <select>, etc).

So the following is valid:

```
<label for="myID">Element A is for Apple</label>
<input id="myID" type="checkbox">
```

but the following is not:

```
<label for="myID">Element A is for Apple</label>
<div id="myID"></div>
```

In fact, if you run the above example through an html validator, https://validator.w3.org/nu, it will flag it in error:

> **Error:** The value of the `for` attribute of the `label` element must be the ID of a non-hidden form control.

Regarding the `label-id` attribute, it does not exist.  It's not part of the html language.  It appears to be a custom attribute but custom attributes should start with "[data-](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/dom.html#custom-data-attribute)".

You **can** have a `<label>` without a `for` attribute such as:

```
<label id="newID">Element A is for Apple</label>
<input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="newID">
```

In this case, the <input> points back to the <label> instead of the <label> pointing to the <input>, but that's a poor use of the <label> element.  You won't gain the benefit of the <label>.  The first example lets you click on the text of the <label> and the checkbox will be selected.  In the last example, while the checkbox will be labeled by the text, you can't click on the text to select the checkbox.

Comment: thanks for the response...i agree with your finding...one of the main issues i ran into was that when i removed the angular and set it up the way you have set it up in the example you replied with, the functionality broke...now i can leave both versions of the html in place (proper way & custom way) i am just concerned that there could be a level of redundancy (as in each element is labeled and read twice)...again this understanding could be a lack of experience...